# reusable partial view with it's controller in asp MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I find a lot of question and answer about this topic but none exhaustive.

I need a simple partial view that get an int parameter, pass it to it's controller that query the db and get entire detail of the record and pass it to view to render it.

also the view must have a button for generating a report to the user (via iTextSharp)

I need to use this partial view in many pages.

This is part of my actual controller of partial view

```
Public class TitleBarController : Controller
    {
        private IUnitOfWork uow;

        // GET: MVC/TitleBar
        public ActionResult Index(int idAttivita)
        {
            TitleBarViewModel tbVM =  Mapper.Map<Attivita, TitleBarViewModel>(uow.Attivita.Read(idAttivita));
            return View(tbVM);
        }

        public TitleBarController(IUnitOfWork uow)
        {
            this.uow = uow;
        }       
    }
```

this is how i insert partial view in master view:

```
@Html.Partial("_TitleBarView", new ViewDataDictionary { { "idAttivita", 1 } });)
```

and this is the first part of partial view:

```
@model ProgettoAttivitaUI.Areas.MVC.Controllers.Shared.TitleBar.TitleBarViewModel

<div>
    <h4>Prova</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            Codice attività
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.IdAttivita)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Descrizione)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Descrizione)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
```

but when i open he master view, the partial view is rendered but without data, debugging it i see that it's controller constructor and index method don't fire

Comment: `@Html.Partial()` does not call a controller method. You need to use `@Html.Action("Index", "TitleBar", new { idAttivita = 1 })` to call the method and render its partial view in the main view.

Comment: use ajax for calling the controller to render partial page

Comment: i get The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:

Comment: Then you have not created a view `Index.cshtml` in `/Views/TitleBar` - if you want to use the `_TitleBarView`, then use `return View("_TitleBarView", tbVM);`

Comment: that's why he always called them "index" :D. thanks again.